# p5.js: slider not updating properly

Tags: javascript, p5.js

i've been recently getting up to scratch with Javascript, and i have been following along with The Coding Train's video about fractal trees in p5js (this video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jjeOYMjmDU).

However, i've been having trouble getting the angle slider to actually work since it doesn't seem to be updating at all whenever i move it (at the video at roughly 10m 15s, his seems to work almost without any issues!)

is there anyone who could shed some light on this issue? my code below is as follows:

```js
let angle;
var slider; //let didnt work, got a "referenceerror cannot access before initialization"

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  slider = createSlider(0, TWO_PI, PI/4, 0.01);
}

function draw() {
  background(51);

  console.log(isLooping()); //debug - prints 'true'
  angle = slider.value();
  console.log(angle); //debug - wrote to test the slider, isn't continually printing, why?
  // let len = 100;
  stroke(255);
  translate(200, height);
  branch(100);


}

function branch(len) {
  line(0, 0, 0, -len);
  translate(0, -len);
  rotate(angle);  // should change when i move the slider, but doesn't
  branch(len * 0.67);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I'm running your p5 sketch I'm getting a recursion error:
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (sketch: line 24)`

Your branch function never returns as it calls itself infinite times.
I made some edits, also see my inline comments.

```js
let angle;
let slider; //let works fine

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  slider = createSlider(0, TWO_PI, PI/4, 0.01);
}

function draw() {
  background(51);

  console.log(isLooping()); //debug - prints 'true'
  angle = slider.value();
  console.log(angle); //debug - wrote to test the slider, isn't continually printing, why?
  // let len = 100;
  stroke(255);
  translate(200, height);
  branch(100, 4); // adjust the second argument to reflect your desired depth of the tree


}

function branch(len, depth) {
  if(depth == 0){
    return
  }
  line(0, 0, 0, -len);
  translate(0, -len);
  rotate(angle);  // should change when i move the slider, but doesn't
  branch(len * 0.67, depth - 1); //calling the recursive function with the 'remaining' branches
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! ran the code snippet in the browser and it worked! I knew i was seeing some errors in my console about that but since it worked in the video's demonstration without including a recursion depth check i just automatically assumed it was because of something else 